# CAShapeLayer : Identify shape : Add CATextLayer in that shape

Tags: ios, objective-c, cashapelayer, svgkit

I have **SVG** file and i was able to access SVG's shapes using `SVGKit`.

Now, I have `CAShapeLayer` which may contain circle, square or any closed shape.

I want to add `CATextLayer` on `CAShapeLayer` in such way that text should not cross the defined shape.

Here is the example of crossing `CATextLayer` on `CAShapeLayer` :

[image] [image]

It's crossing just because, `CATextLayer` is starting from 0 position of `CAShapeLayer` which contains circle in particular this case.

In my case, `CAShapeLayer` can contain any closed shape. It can be oval also.

How can I identify shape inside `CAShapeLayer`? or How can I apply path to `CATextLayer`? which will makes sure text will be drawn inside shape?

Here is code to add `CATextLayer` On `CAShapeLayer`:

```
-(CATextLayer *)addTrackerNumberToLayer:(NSString *)numbers{
    self.numbersTextLayer = [CATextLayer new];
    self.numbersTextLayer.foregroundColor = [UIColor blackColor].CGColor;
    self.numbersTextLayer.font = (__bridge CFTypeRef _Nullable)([UIFont boldSystemFontOfSize:15]);
    self.numbersTextLayer.fontSize=25;
    self.numbersTextLayer.anchorPoint = CGPointZero;
    self.numbersTextLayer.frame = CGRectMake(self.parentShapeLayer.bounds.size.width*0.05, self.parentShapeLayer.bounds.size.height*0.05, self.parentShapeLayer.bounds.size.width*0.90, self.parentShapeLayer.bounds.size.height*0.30);
    self.numbersTextLayer.position = CGPointMake(self.parentShapeLayer.bounds.size.width*0.05,self.parentShapeLayer.bounds.size.height*0.05);
    self.numbersTextLayer.alignmentMode = kCAAlignmentCenter;

    [self.parentShapeLayer addSublayer:self.numbersTextLayer];
}
```

Comment: Share your code.

Comment: added code snippet

Answer (score 0):

Use `isWrapped` property of `CATextLayer` this determines whether the text is wrapped to fit within the receiver’s bounds.

```
-(CATextLayer *)addTrackerNumberToLayer:(NSString *)numbers{
    self.numbersTextLayer = [CATextLayer new];
    self.numbersTextLayer.foregroundColor = [UIColor blackColor].CGColor;
    self.numbersTextLayer.font = (__bridge CFTypeRef _Nullable)([UIFont boldSystemFontOfSize:15]);
    self.numbersTextLayer.fontSize=25;
    self.numbersTextLayer.anchorPoint = CGPointZero;
    self.numbersTextLayer.frame = CGRectMake(self.parentShapeLayer.bounds.size.width*0.05, self.parentShapeLayer.bounds.size.height*0.05, self.parentShapeLayer.bounds.size.width*0.90, self.parentShapeLayer.bounds.size.height*0.30);
    self.numbersTextLayer.position = CGPointMake(self.parentShapeLayer.bounds.size.width*0.05,self.parentShapeLayer.bounds.size.height*0.05);
    self.numbersTextLayer.alignmentMode = kCAAlignmentCenter;
    [self.numbersTextLayer setWrapped:YES];//User Wrapped to YES to imbound the text to fit in the region.
    [self.parentShapeLayer setMasksToBounds:YES];
    [self.parentShapeLayer addSublayer:self.numbersTextLayer];
    return self.numbersTextLayer;
}
```

Comment: No, It didn't work. Because Labels are not drawing outside of CATextLayer. I have added CATextLayer on CAShapeLayer(which contains green circle for now.) So I want to restrict CATextLayer up to defined shape in CAShapeLayer.